# How to turn elementor section into clickable button

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, elementor

Link: http://up8.431.myftpupload.com/services/

I need to turn the section on the page above into clickable buttons. I'm using WordPress with the elementor plugin installed.

I've already added some extra CSS to make the sections appear to clickable. I just need to add the actual functionality. I understand this is done with javascript. I haven't tried adding any javascript code yet. I'm a little hesitant too because I don't think I have the skill and knowledge to do it properly. I don't want to just start adding code everywhere. Past experience has thought me that's a bad idea.

I'm hoping someone experience with elementor can help me out. Here's where I'm stuck:
    Where do I add the javascript? There's nowhere for me to add javascript like there is a section for CSS for each element. Should I add it in the customizer (Appearance --> Customize --> Custom CSS/JS)? Should I get a plugin for custom javascript? I've already given each element a custom class. I could attach some JS to these classes.

EDIT: Thought about it a little more. I don't think adding the JS in the Customizer is the way to go. I'm thinking any CSS/JS I add there should be exclusive for the topbar, header, and footer. My reasoning is because these are the sections that will show up the exact same way on each page. 
That leaves me with the option of getting a JS plugin. Is this the best way?

What would be the best way to accomplish what I need to. I definitly don't have the skill to understand the Elementor Developer Docs. It's way too advanced for me. That's why I'm asking here.

Thx in advance

Comment: There should be an option to add link on the Elementor builder no?

Comment: No. I don't see any option like that. My first instinct was to look for something like that also due to the intuitive nature of elementor.

Comment: This is how I get. https://prnt.sc/mjwg5k and for button: https://prnt.sc/mjwgud I suggest you deal with the plugin issue first, if any. Or else you can also try a temporary jQuery hack like this: `jQuery('[data-id=62f0f1fd] .elementor-column-wrap .elementor-widget-wrap').wrap('<a href="http://google.com" window="_new" />')`

Answer (score 0):

if you know how-to and it's through javascript you can do it this way:
Drag and drop HTML widget-> insert your js between script tags.

I recommened using html in your footer(made with elementor) so the script will be available in entire site.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27121736)

Comment: He is looking for a way to add javascript in elementor. The only way to do so (without a plugin) is what I mentioned. I don't see how you found the answer as "not answer"!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way to do so without any plugin or js, just CSS:

First we need to set a minimum height for our Section/Column (I set 50vh);

then we have to add an element which has link/a tag (e.g. Title Widget) and set a CSS class for that (in my example .mhdizmni_title);

now we have to write a bit of css:

```
.mhdizmni_title a:after {
content: "";
display: block !IMPORTANT;
position: absolute;
height: 50vh;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this and think I have a solution. It does not require any plug in and only minimal CSS code. I will include it below...

I essentially turned a column into something that resembled a button using borders and margins and then added some CSS code to give it a hover effect, the code is here:

```
selector:hover > .elementor-widget-wrap {
background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

selector:hover {
transform: translateY(-5px);
transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}

selector {
transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
}

selector:not(:hover) {
transform: translateY(0);
}
```

Change the hex (#) background colour at the beginning to get your desired hover effect and the translate Y pixels and ease in and out for the 'lift' effect given to the button (actually a column disguised as a button). Important to note here that you need to add the custom CSS to the COLUMN widget, rather than what you might put inside it (I used an inner section to add text and an emoji to my 'button').

I used the heading widget within an inner section in my column (now appearing as a button) and added a link directly to the heading. Only issue now is that it's only when you hover over the text that the link is clickable. To get the link to spread to the entirety of the box, you need to add the following CSS to the HEADER widget this time (not the column widget like I instructed before):

```
selector {
cursor: pointer;
}
selector a {
display: block;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Stack overflow has given me warnings that my code isnt formatted properly. I'm new to this so not sure what to do. I have a google doc with the formatted code in it here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JnOQERbA2cpV9ADVzpMl_pdk6dnUui509B6dPJ66RnQ/edit

I hope this makes sense. I have outlined it in a YouTube video. Please check it out to see if my explanation is what you are after. Here is the YouTube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W96U7MnD_HQ&ab_channel=ElliotMcCluskey